# Need "Is the point in the pie?" in SQL

Tags: sql, position, geometry, computational-geometry

In my SQL Table `pie_on_coords`, I have following

```
  id  |  direction_angle  |  pie_angle  |  position_x  |  position_y  |  pie_radius
```

Entries correspond something like this:

[image: pie_sample]

I supposed to find entries, which cover given point `(x,y)`

But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) `(r, phi)` of point `(x, y) - (position_x, position_y)` in `([0,pie_radius], [direction_angle - pie_angle/2, direction_angle + pie_angle/2])`.

```
px = x - position_x
py = y - position_y
r = sqrt( px^2 + py^2 )
phi = atan2(py/px)
```

Point is in if:

```
r <= pie_radius
direction_angle - pie_angle/2 <= phi <= direction_angle + pie_angle/2
```

Take a care if `direction_angle - pie_angle/2 < -pi` or `direction_angle + pie_angle/2 > pi`.